# Styled components: How to style FC as child inside styled parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I would like to complete the style of a FC styled element as a child inside an other styled element.

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-styled-components-forked-9cnhx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```js
const ColorTextContainer = styled.div`
  font-weight: bold;

  ${RedBackgroundDiv} {
    color: white;
  }
`;
```

This give the error : `No overload matches this call.` [[...]](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-styled-components-forked-9cnhx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```js
const ColorTextContainer = styled.div(() => ({
  fontSize: 30,

  RedBackgroundDiv: {
    color: "white"
  }
}));
```

This just not apply white color to `RedBackgroundDiv` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedBackgroundDiv` is the component, where you need to target the generated `className`, try passing the `Container` value:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
`;

const RedBackgroundDiv: FC & {className: string} = ({ children }) => {
  return <Container>{children}</Container>;
};

RedBackgroundDiv.className = Container;

// Usage
const ColorTextContainer = styled.div(() => ({
  fontSize: 30,

// [Container]: {...}
  [RedBackgroundDiv.className]: {
    color: "white"
  },

  "div.blue": {
    color: "blue"
  }
}));
```

[image: Edit React TypeScript Styled-components (forked)]

Comment: What is the correct syntax to add css selector to `[RedBackgroundDiv.className]` ? For example `> [RedBackgroundDiv.className]` to get direct first childs. Or `[RedBackgroundDiv.className]:first-of-type`, or a className directly attributed to `<RedBackgroundDiv></RedBackgroundDiv>` in the container.

Comment: Does this question related to the original? I guess you should ask in a different thread. I would check the right syntax by reading the related doc section

Comment: I think yes, it does. "How to style FC as child". Add css selector is consistent with the question I guess, to correctly apply style to the element. It could be in the example.